# How can I create a virtual serial which pyserial can read?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, arduino, pyserial

I'm using **pyserial**, running on an **Ubuntu** machine, to talk to a couple of Arduinos. I'm currently developing some Python software to get data from those Arduinos; however, I don't always have access to said hardware, and so I'd like to set up a couple of **virtual** serials - which I can write data to, and which pyserial can read - in order to test and further develop my code.

I'm aware that this is question that has popped up more than once on this site. However, I've yet to find a solution that works on my machine. Please help me!

---

P. S. I asked [a more specific version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753616/ser-inwaiting-always-returns-0-when-reading-a-virtual-port?noredirect=1#comment101951288_57753616) yesterday, but I didn't get any bites, hence why I've asked the same question today in a broader form.

Answer (score 1):

You can download some `free virtual serial port` applications which can create virtual port for your testing.

Comment: Thanks for this. openpty seems promising, but do you know how to use it? The various manuals floating around online seem to imply that you need to root around in some C code to get it working, which I can do, but I'd rather avoid. If you don't know how to use openpty, is there a specific application you could recommend?

Comment: I am currently using this app https://freevirtualserialports.com/, I hope it work for you too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Linux, so this won't work for me.